# QGIS 2.18 selected features not working in processing algorithms

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

After reading up on processing algorithms I see there is not an option to have a "selected features" checkbox.  It states in the documentation:

Algorithms follow the following simple rules when using a vector layer.

```
If the layer has a selection, only selected features are used.
If there is no selection, all features are used.
```

However, when I run a process such as 'Random selection' from the Processing Toolbox all items (in my case all points), are processed, not just the features I have selected.  I have gone into the Processing - Options - General menu and have selected/deselected 'Use only selected features' but no success?

Am I not proceeding correctly or is/was there a bug in v2.18?

Comment: Why QGIS 2.18 ?!

Comment: I believe I have found the answer by using Random Extract within Subset instead of Random Selection.